# Using bound argument name inside python function

Tags: python, function, variable-binding

My current hackish manner of printing multiple arrays in columns uses keyword arguments to label the output:

```
def table(**data_dict):
    n=([len(x) for x in data_dict.values()]) # # data for each var
    N=max(n)
    # prep data & print headings
    prntstr=''
    for i,var in enumerate(data_dict):
        # convert lists to str for printing, padding as needed
        data_dict[var] = ['{:.5g}'.format(x) for x in data_dict[var]] + ['']*(N-n[i]) 
        prntstr=prntstr+f'| {var:^8} |'
    print(prntstr,'-'*12*len(data_dict),sep='\n'); # print heading 
    # print data
    for i in range(0,N):
        prntstr=' '.join(f'{data_dict[var][i]:>11}' for var in data_dict)
        print(prntstr)
```

and used

```
rho=[1.5,0.11]
Fx=[-14.2]
table(rho=rho,T=[665,240],Fx=Fx)
```

producing

```
|   rho    ||    T     ||    Fx    |
------------------------------------
        1.5         665       -14.2
       0.11         240
```

Is there another way to do this that can use the bound argument name (e.g rho) and avoid the repetition (e.g. rho=rho) for non-keyword arguments so that one could type simply `table(rho,T=[665,240],Fx)`?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think Python has a shorthand like that.

Comment: I suspect if there is one, it's gonna be *actually* hackish. (Like inspecting the stack frames and trying to figure out variable names from the received objects.)

Comment: Unless you know the positional names ahead of time, there's not likely any practical solution. If you do know the positional names ahead of time, or have some way to discern them based on the value alone, then maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Use RHO=rho where RHO is the heading in the output.

Replace

```
table(rho=rho,T=[665,240],Fx=Fx)
```

with

```
table(RHO=rho,T=[665,240],Fx=Fx)
```

If this is not acceptable you will have to accept the first argument

Replace

```
def table(**data_dict)
```

with

```
def table(RHO, **data_dict):
    data_dict['rho'] = RHO
```

and call as follows:

Replace

```
table(rho=rho,T=[665,240],Fx=Fx)
```

with

```
table(rho,T=[665,240],Fx=Fx)
```